# Best way to install new vent pipe?

Tags: plumbing, venting

In my house, the kitchen is on one side of the house, and bathrooms on the other side.  For some reason, the kitchen drains are not vented at all, but bathrooms are.  I would like to vent the kitchen plumbing, and I was wondering what would be the best way to do this?  Here are some options I thought of given my house configuration:

1. Run pipe from one side of the house to the other to connect into the vent stack, but this would be a very long run and a lot of effort passing through all the joists in the basement literally going the length of the house.
2. Install a "cheater vent" (1 way valve).  This would be perfect, but I need the vent to allow gas exchange in both directions.  This is because my basement has an ejector pump (into a septic tank), and the lack of venting on the kitchen side is causing the pressure from the pump to push gasses past the traps when it runs.  This is the big reason why I want to add venting.
3. Run a new vent stack through the roof?? Is there a better way than going all the way through the roof?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!  Thanks for your time.

EDIT: More info.  The vent stack is behind the drywall ceiling in the basement bathroom, so not much access, but there is a vent branch extending into the exposed joists in the oil tank room next to it that I could tie into.  The access beneath the kitchen is completely open. (only some of the basement is finished at this time).

I would call myself a very capable DIY'er.  I have a good deal of experience in plumbing, framing, electrical, concrete work, etc.  I don't have any issues tearing into things.  Although one area I don't have much experience in is doing work on the roof so when it comes to this I have a bit of apprehension, but would be willing to do what ever to get it done.

Comment: The answer has a lot do do with things we don't know, such as access, your tolerance for cutting things open, your skillset, local codes, etc. I'm not sure what answer we an provide that helps you much. I'd get a local someone to take a look with you and suggest a plan.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I added more info that may or may not be useful. I will none-the-less try to look for someone to take a look.  I like to try to do everything myself so I lean that way.

Comment: Given that it's vents, look above. *i.e.* run a pipe through the attic rather than drilling all the joists in the basement. Or provide details as to why that direction is deemed impractical...

Comment: Probably have to call a plumber. I'm thinking that the venting near your ejector pump may have a clog/restriction or the ejector pump is oversized for the venting.